# T-SQL - get value between two dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I just watched such an example which shows how to get all cols by date here it is...

```
DECLARE @MyGetDate DATETIME

SELECT @MyGetDate = '2 Mar 2003 21:40'

SELECT  * 
FROM @Table
WHERE convert(varchar, @MyGetDate, 14) BETWEEN convert(varchar, startDate, 14) AND convert(varchar, endDate, 14)
```

... but the thing is I was trying to modify it as to get values within past 50 minutes. Here it is

```
SELECT  value, my_date_col
FROM myTable
WHERE convert(varchar, my_date_col, 14) BETWEEN convert(varchar, dateadd(minute, -50, getdate()), 14) AND convert(varchar, getdate(), 14)
```

But it doesn't work :( So my question is how to use col **my_date_col** in such kind of statement?

Any useful comment is appreciated

Comment: Why are you converting your DATETIME types to VARCHAR? Just compare them directly.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work either :( So I tried to base on this topic http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: "it didn't work" is a _very_ poor description of a problem. **What** didn't work? What did you expect to happen? What didn't happen? What did happen instead?

Comment: I converted just because I tried to get date minutes (past 50 min date) the index '14' as shown in the web page example table http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/ but I am not sure it is a really an optimal way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `my_date_col` is DateTime column, then you don't need the casting. Casting is needed because the sample uses string representation of dates.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE()

SELECT value, my_date_col 
FROM myTable WHERE my_date_col BETWEEN dateadd(minute, -50, @date) AND @date
```

Comment: It would be better if you put `dateadd(minute, -50, @date)` into a variable outside the query

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine, assuming `my_date_col` is a `DATETIME`:

```
SELECT  value, my_date_col
FROM myTable
WHERE my_date_col BETWEEN dateadd(minute, -50, getdate()) AND getdate()
```

If nothing is returned, there are *no* rows with a `my_date_col` in the last 50 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the CONVERT statements, you want to compare dates, not varchars.

```
SELECT  value, my_date_col
FROM myTable
WHERE  my_date_col BETWEEN dateadd(minute, -50, getdate()) AND getdate(), 14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select value1, date_column from @Table
WHERE date_column between date1 and date2
```